# How to use background:url(data:image/png;base64 with Retina?

Tags: css

I noticed that an image embedded into css with Data URI scheme is displayed on Retina screens with "regular" resolution. How to embed and image with resolution required by the Retina display?

I didn't try to embed a double resolution (@2) PNG into CSS, but I suspect that it would be displayed in double size, similar to regular images when size of the image is not defined.

Comment: You could use the `background-size` property to resize the 2x background to 50%, which should scale the image to the right size on both displays.

Comment: I think inlined base64 images will not have Retina resolution. It is not supported yet. I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Two images can have the same resolution but different dpi. This is the important part in retina displays, therefore, you need two versions (if you want to save some bandwith for those that doesn't have retina) of you image with different dpi's.

For further information on how to add a rule in css, and some dpi values take a look at: [Retina Display Media Query](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

**EDIT**
As pointed out by a comment from @carlos-r-balebona, bandwith will not be saved if embed the image into the CSS, as both versions will always be sent. It will only be saved if you use image URLs as only the proper one will be downloaded.

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE**

OK, here's an example:

Suppose you have 2 images (data:image/png;base64,{192_dpi_encoded_image}) and (data:image/png;base64,{96_dpi_encoded_image}).

Now suppose you have a div you want to set the background image to:

```
<div id="a" style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
</div>
```

And in your css:

```
@media only screen
{
     #a
    {
        background:url(data:image/png;base64,{96_dpi_encoded_image});
    }
}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx){
    #a
    {
        background:url(data:image/png;base64,{192_dpi_encoded_image});
    }
}
```

The last @media with conditions will override the background image set before only if there's a retina screen present, thus, setting the large dpi image when needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this article is usefull, but doesn't answer my question. I asked specifically about embedded images, e.g.

Comment: In the example above, using base64 version of the images, you are not going to save bandwidth. By the time css's media queries are filtering, the entire css file (with both versions of the image encoded) have already been sent to the client.

Comment: You are right, the "save bandwith" stuff is for when you add a URL instead of an encoded image (only one will be downloaded). In this case, as both are already on the encoded CSS there's no bandtiwh saved, but I was not trying to relate those things, I assumed that knowing those images are embedded at the CSS would never save bandwith at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the background size in pixels (the values should be the original dimensions divided by two, if your image has 2x resolution):

```
.element {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;asdkfasdkf);
  background-size: 25px 50px;
}
```